# How to recognize six characters from an image by using pytesseract

Tags: python-tesseract

[image]

I can't understand how to recognize it.
Hope someone can get me out.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image


image = cv2.imread('b.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Morph open to remove noise and invert image
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)
invert = 255 - opening

data = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng', config='--psm 10')
print(data)
```

Comment: Captchas are explicitly designed to NOT be solved by (simple) OCR routines. You might find a solution for that specific captcha only incorporating simple image-processing methods, but most likely that solution will fail on the next input.